# putty - need recent standard output

Tags: linux, putty

I am in a situation where I need to view everything that was output to the screen recently in my putty session. Unfortunately, I can only view the last 200 lines. Is there any way to do this? The putty window is still open, if that helps.

Comment: Increase the size of the scrollback buffer, I commonly use 2000 lines of scrollback.

Comment: Any way to view it presently?

Comment: Check if you have not logging enabled (in options) by chance.

Comment: session logging isn't checked

Comment: in putty configuration (that's the thing you see when starting putty, with on the left a tree with options Session, Terminal, Window, Connection and a bunch of subioptions), option Window, it's quite appropriately called `Lines of scrollback`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use screen command:

```
http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/
```

or see a manual:

```
man screen
```

and then log output with:

```
“Ctrl-A” “H”
```